# How to make message entry/list/view in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, templates, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

He I am a beginner to C# and I am working on a reaction manager plug-in for some bigger project. (Yes I am a intern)

Now I just can't find a way to create a view similar to this:

[image]

My full design:

[image]

How to realize this design? I cant find any default templates in the devexpress which are suitable for this. I come from php and in php I can use html. I am a beginner to C# and I don't have any clue on how t do this. Do I have to use canvas to literally draw this? OR is there a standard template I can use for this purpose.

Comment: winforms or wpf? or is this web?

Comment: No this is for a standalone desktop application. I am just experimenting with winforms right now. You know any component which I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many comment boxes that contain the same layout - a label comment text, author name, date, etc. There is no control that lays things out like that, you will have to make your own custom control (Project->Add User Control). This control will be a composite control - ie made up of other controls. Probably a label for each text field (comment, author, date, etc) laid out in the right places. Maybe call it CommentBox or something.

Then in the main form you now have available CommentBox controls which you can add to the form. Create a panel to put them in so you have many CommentBox controls in the panel, one for each comment (or maybe add them at runtime).

Now in WPF it's slightly easier because there is a [StackPanel control](http://wpftutorial.net/StackPanel.html) that you can simply add controls to and it automatically arranges them vertically one beneath another in a stacked list. In fact your use case is exactly fitting what a StackPanel is for.

In WinForms there is no StackPanel, but you can use a normal Panel control*. It's just you'll have to position the CommentBox controls manually one beneath another. You will also need to set the AutoScroll property to true to turn on the vertical scroll bar if the content doesn't fit the view.

*or there's apparently an alternative [How can I get a StackPanel-like layout in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299704/how-can-i-get-a-stackpanel-like-layout-in-winforms)

Comment: Well I tried with WPF stackpanel and that is working out for me. And now I see an html/xml based markup code I am on the road again thank you.